# Фильтр в Джанго

Tags: python, django

Чего-то не получается сделать фильтр в питоне. Идея такая: Мне надо выбрать все объекты у которых нет не одного потомка и тех, у которых потомки имеют бал равный нулю. Я могу написать два выражения отдельно, а как написать их вместе не нашел. Буду рад ответу, а еще больше ссылке на ман.

Объекты без потомков

```
objects.filter(children__isnull=True)
```

Объекты с потомками по ноль баллов

```
objects.filter(children__point=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно написать так:

```
objects.filter(children__isnull=True, children__point=0)
```

UPD: Я понял вопрос как пересечение (AND) запросов. Если требуется объединение (OR), нужно использовать объект `Q`.

Comment: Спс. Вопрос, как оказалось, дико простой, но просто не найти было, как не гугли, нет в рунете такого :(.

Answer (score 1):

Если я понял правильно, то делай так:

```
from django.db.models import Q
...filter(Q(children__isnull=True) | Q(children__point=0))
```

Вообще почитай [вот это](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: По ссылке много чего по фильтрации, читай официальные доки :)

Comment: Уже в процессе :). Ссылка классная.